# Dynamics CRM 2016 Javascript fix

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have the following situation in Dynamics CRM 2016.

I am trying to create a JS web resource that will act on a dropdown field change.

```js
function esitoappuntamento() {
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_esito").addOnChange(myOnChange);

  function myOnChange() {
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_esito").getSelectedOption().value == "100000006") {
      Xrm.Page.getControl("new_esitoapp").setVisible(false); 
      Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_esitoapp").setRequiredLevel("none");
    }
    else {
      Xrm.Page.getControl("new_esitoapp").setVisible(true);  
      Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_esitoapp").setRequiredLevel("required");
    }
  }
}
```

I have the option set field `new_esito` with options/choices. What I want to do is to show the `new_esitoapp` field only when the form loads and the new_esito value is 100000006 and someone changes the value from 100000006 to something else from the remaining 7 choices.

Otherwise if when the form loads the `new_esito` value is not 100000006, it should not show the `new_esitoapp` field independently from what I choose in the `new_esito` field from the 8 available choices.

This is working partially as I need it to work, because it is working fine for the case when the form loads and the field value is 100000006.

The problem is that it is still showing the `new_esitoapp` field even when the form loads and the value of `new_esito` is not 100000006 and I change it to something else.

So the behavior should be:

```
Form load -> new_esito = 100000006 -> change new_esito -> show new_esitoapp

Form load -> new_esito != 100000006 -> change new_esito -> no show new_esitoapp
```

Wrong behavior now is:

```
Form load -> new_esito != 100000006 -> change new_esito -> show new_esitoapp
```

I hope I made myself clear about what I want to achieve.

Looking forward to your replies.

Regards

Comment: Are you calling this myOnChange function on form load or not? Atleast fireOnChange() will help you..

Comment: This shouldn't matter since you're using `==` rather than `===` but the Option Set value in Turbo Forms are ints, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should fire your show\hide action on OnLoad of the form. More details here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/events/form-onload
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334701.aspx

Yours function myOnChange should be triggered both on OnLoad of the form and on OnChange of your new_esito attribute.

The other option is to utilize business rules:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-business-rules-recommendations-apply-logic-form

Comment: I have tried to fire the above web resource on both OnLoad and OnChange but I have the problem explained above.

About the Business Rules, it is not possible to achieve what I need to achieve with Business Rules because Business Rules do not consider the initial value. if my initial value is 100000006 and I change that value, it should show the new_esitoapp which with business rules is not possible to do because Business Rules do not care what the initial value is.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your js and reload the form. Most probably it won't hit lines where you call setVisible. Make sure you are calling right js function on yours form load and they it really gets called.

Comment: I got you. Here is link with potential workaround: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3acfdf7-8b7a-491c-be63-6bb752c52f4d/crm2011-how-to-get-before-after-value-in-the-onchange-event?forum=crmdevelopment

But from my point of view that's looks like a bad business process. Since I can set the new_esito to whatever I like, refresh form and get that hiding field...

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. It's totally different to what I want to achieve and it's related to Dynamics CRM 2011

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you are just writing an eventhandler `myOnChange` and binding it to `onChange` event of `new_esito` using `addOnChange`.

When you call this `esitoappuntamento` on form load, its bound & ready to fire next time when change happens.

But you are not triggering it until unless, you fire that using `fireOnChange`. All these are dynamic way of doing on the fly.

The other way of binding this is in form editor, adding the `onChange` event under field properties. Which will bind it to control & trigger it during form onload itself.